# Create list of object from another using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to understand Java 8 streams.
I have two classes:

```
public class UserMeal {
    protected final LocalDateTime dateTime;

    protected final String description;

    protected final int calories;

    public UserMeal(LocalDateTime dateTime, String description, int calories) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.description = description;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class UserMealWithExceed {
    protected final LocalDateTime dateTime;

    protected final String description;

    protected final int calories;

    protected final boolean exceed;

    public UserMealWithExceed(LocalDateTime dateTime, String description, int calories, boolean exceed) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.description = description;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.exceed = exceed;
    }
}
```

The `exceed` field should indicate whether the sum of calories for the entire day. This field is the same for all entries for that day.

I try to get object from `List<UserMeal> mealList`, group by the day, calculate calories for a period of time, and create `List<UserMealWithExceed>`:

```
public static List<UserMealWithExceed>  getFilteredMealsWithExceeded(List<UserMeal> mealList, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime, int caloriesPerDay) {

    return mealList.stream()
            .filter(userMeal -> userMeal.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isAfter(startTime)&&userMeal.getDateTime().toLocalTime().isBefore(endTime))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(userMeal -> userMeal.getDateTime().getDayOfMonth(),
                         Collectors.summingInt(userMeal -> userMeal.getCalories())))
            .forEach( ????? );
}
```

but I don't understand how to create new object in `forEach` and return collection.

How I see in pseudocode:

```
.foreach( 
    if (sumCalories>caloriesPerDay)
    {return new UserMealWithExceed(userMeal.getdateTime, usermeal.getDescription, usermeal.getCalories, true);}
    else
    {return new UserMealWithExceed(userMeal.getdateTime, usermeal.getDescription, usermeal.getCalories, false)
    }
)//foreach
```

Comment: Simply, don’t use `forEach`. A [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) supports more operations than this one.

Answer (score 177):

If you want to iterate over a list and create a new list with "transformed" objects, you should use the `map()` function of stream + `collect()`. In the following example I find all people with the last name "l1" and each person I'm "mapping" to a new Employee instance.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
                new Person("e1", "l1"),
                new Person("e2", "l1"),
                new Person("e3", "l2"),
                new Person("e4", "l2")
        );

        List<Employee> employees = persons.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals("l1"))
                .map(p -> new Employee(p.getName(), p.getLastName(), 1000))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(employees);
    }

}

class Person {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Getter & Setter
}

class Employee extends Person {

    private double salary;

    public Employee(String name, String lastName, double salary) {
        super(name, lastName);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! I used similar pattern to convert a list of database entities to DTO's

Comment: What about the case were Employee only has a no-arg constructor?

Comment: @csmith49 you can instantiate the object and call the set methods inside the `map` function. You can have a better look on lambda expressions on http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html and http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips

Comment: Yeah thanks, I didn't see your message until now but worked it out myself yesterday, good to know this is the correct way to do it:
List<Employee> employeeList = persons.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals("l1"))                
                .map(p ->
                {
                    Employee e = new Employee();
                    e.setName(p.getName());
                    e.setSalary(p.getSalary());
                    return e;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but how to return multiple objects, eg: .map(p -> {
    return p + new Employee(p.getName(), p.getLastName(), 1000)
}). As I need to return new object with p.

Comment: @RinsenS you can use the `flatMap()` method to do that, you can create a new List inside it with 'p' and the new entity and return that list stream

Comment: @RafaelTeles, but its gets quite big and complicated as I need to check for particular value of p eg: if p.getName() == 'A' , then if p.getNumber() != null , create a list with p and new class('B', p.getNumber()) and return the list, is there any other efficient way, thanks !!

Answer (score 20):

What you are possibly looking for is `map()`. You can "convert" the objects in a stream to another by mapping this way:

```java
...
 .map(userMeal -> new UserMealExceed(...))
...
```

Answer (score 6):

An addition to the solution by @Rafael Teles. The syntactic sugar `Collectors.mapping` does the same in one step:

```
//...
List<Employee> employees = persons.stream()
  .filter(p -> p.getLastName().equals("l1"))
  .collect(
    Collectors.mapping(
      p -> new Employee(p.getName(), p.getLastName(), 1000),
      Collectors.toList()));
```

Detailed example can be found [here](https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-how-to-use-collectors-mapping-collector-with-examples/)