# Build list from nested object in apache freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have a list of object and I want to get a list from its field.
Say I pass `List<Auto> autos` from java side to the template on the document side. Each Auto has a field of speed.
So the result should be list of speed.
I can do it manually looping through the autos and building a new list from the speed fields.
Is there any easier solution built in for this in the freemarker something like `'autos.speed?tolist'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the sequence built-in [`map`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_map), which is available from version 2.3.29. It returns a new sequence where all elements are replaced with the result of the parameter lambda, function, or method. This allows you to do:

```
autos?map(auto -> auto.speed)
```

If you want to do this in Java, see:

- [Create list of object from another using Java 8 Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650974/create-list-of-object-from-another-using-java-8-streams)

There it comes down to:

```
autos.stream().map(Auto::getSpeed).collect(Collectors.toList());
```